# Keep commit history of a branch in git log graph after git merge

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

### Test case:

```
                 A---B---C topic
                /
           D---E master
```

If I do

```
git checkout master
git merge topic
```

I'll get

```
               D---E---A---B---C master,topic
```

How can I merge so that the commit graph remains like the following

```
                     A---B---C topic
                    /         \
               D---E-----------F master
```

Comment: [`--no-ff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---no-ff)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a **one-shot approach**, you can do

```
git merge topic --no-ff
```

and it will force the merge commit (see [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---no-ff)).

---

But also note that if you need to have that on a repo as part of your general workflow, you can set it in your **config to never fast-forward merge** even when possible, with

```
git config merge.ff false
```